# Error extends AccountController.php in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, controllers

I'm trying to extend the core AccountController.php -> app/code/core/Mage/Customer copied it to app/code/local/Mage/ and add a log to see which extends properly.

```
In the file AccountController.php (app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers)
...
...
public function createPostAction() {
        Mage::log('In app/code/local/Mage/', null, 'test.log', true);
...
...

AND CORE (only test)
In the file AccountController.php (app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers)
...
...
public function createPostAction() {
        Mage::log('In app/code/core/Mage/', null, 'test.log', true);
...
...
```

And does not go through code/local/ Mage but by CORE. I need to configure something or it fails?

So I created a separate module following this tutorial: http:// aqpredict.com/blog/overriding-account-contoller-magento/ does not work.

anyone has an example of this, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I [answered this question of yours over at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595975/error-extends-accountcontroller-php-in-magento/17612264#17612264):

> The logic through which controller class definitions are loaded builds the path to the file *above* the explicit include paths on which the autoloader relies. This means no local vs. core precedence.
>
> You need to creat a controller rewrite by specifying a directory under the xpath `frontend/routers/customer/args/modules/your_module`
>
> The latter node needs the `before` attribute set to `Mage_Customer` and you will need to create an *`AccountController.php`* with a `createPostAction()` method. Depending on your needs you may or may not need to extend from *and require* the core account controller class.

Comment: sorry did not see the answer on StackOverflow, I've created a new module in the config add a rewrite is that right?
You have an example of how it should be or I send the structure of everything and tell me I'm doing wrong.?

Comment: My example is in my code. Follow the directions (create xpath, etc.) and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your module etc/config.xml

```
<frontend>
  <routers>
    <customer>
      <args>
        <modules>
          <your_module before="Mage_Customer">Your_Module_Customer</your_module>
        </modules>
      </args>
    </customer>
  </routers>
</frontend>
```

Now create your custom AccountController in Your/Module/controllers/Customer/AccountController.php

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage'.DS.'Customer'.DS.'controllers'.DS.'AccountController.php';
class Your_Module_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController {
    // Here you can override your methods
}
```